# Vuejs: how to remove curly bracket "{}" in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I have data like this:

```js
{
    success: true,
    message: "success",
    data: {
        schedule_id: 2,
        estimated_practice_time: "20",
        day: "{0,1}",
        from_time: "{08:00:00,09:00:00}",
        until_time: "{18:00:00,19:00:00}"
    }
}
```

For now, this is my result:

[image]

I want to display only the value on "day", without curly braces, only

```
0,1
```

Comment: do you want them inside an array?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim in the view or console is fine

Comment: how is that whole object is defined ?

Comment: The object is defined like this : [View.vue](https://pastebin.com/iXW4MTyW)

Comment: in your data property you have `day:'{1,2}'`? means that you could access it like `this.day`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a computed property in which you could replace the curly brackets by empty string  :

```
computed:{
     customDay(){
         return this.obj.data.day.replace(/[{}]/g,'');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to achieve it

```js
let a = '{1,2}'
a = a.replace(/[{}]/g, '');
console.log(a)
```